# What is $\omega \otimes 2$? Is it $\omega \cdot 2$ or $\omega +1$?

Tags: ordinals, combinatorial-game-theory

I am reading about nim operations extended to ordinals (developed by Conway).

In Siegel's Combinatorial Game Theory, Lemma 4.4 (page 440) states that if $\gamma$ is a field where every polynomial of degree $\leq n$ has a root in $\alpha$, then polynomials of degree $\leq n$ and coefficients $< \gamma$ are evaluated normally, that is, with the classic sum and product operations of ordinals.

As $\omega$ is a quadratically closed field (this is in fact a classic game theory result), $\omega \otimes 2 = \omega \cdot 2$
However, I wanted to compute $\omega \otimes 2$ with the recursive definition, that is:

$\alpha \otimes \beta = mex \{ \alpha' \otimes \beta : \alpha \otimes \beta' : \alpha' < \alpha,\beta' < \beta\}$

So I have to know the results of $\omega \otimes 1, \omega \otimes 0$, and $n \otimes 2$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

$\omega \otimes 1 = 1, \omega \otimes 0 = 0$; those are easy.

As $\omega$ is a field, in particular every natural number has an inverse in $\omega$. In fact, $\frac{1}{2}=3 \in \mathbb{N}$. Take $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then taking $n= \frac{k}{2} = k \otimes 3$, we have that $n \otimes 2 = k \otimes 3 \otimes 2 = k$.

So $n \otimes 2$ is suryective in $\omega$ (and stays in $\omega$ as $\omega$ is a field and is closed under nim product).

So $\omega \otimes 2 = mex \{0,\omega,n : n\in \omega\} = mex\ \omega +1 = \omega + 1$. This is different from $\omega \cdot 2$.

I don't understand why! Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I don't have Siegel's book, but that's not the recursive definition of $\alpha\otimes\beta$ in ONAG.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had it wrong. I got confused with the definition of the ordinal sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of $\alpha\otimes\beta$ is wrong.  The correct definition is $$\alpha\otimes\beta=\mathrm{mex}\{\alpha'\otimes\beta\oplus\alpha\otimes\beta'\oplus \alpha'\otimes\beta':\alpha'<\alpha,\beta'<\beta\}.$$

Comment: You know, it's quite a hard definition to work with. It requires infinite steps to evaluate the product of infinite ordinals :-(

Comment: Here's how to get $\omega\otimes2$ in finitely many steps. First observe that $\beta'$ must be $0$ or $1$. Substituting each of these candidates in turn gives respectively $2\alpha'$ and $\omega+3\alpha'$ in the mex argument. As $2$ and $3$ have multiplicative inverses in the finite nimbers these arguments respectively cover all of $n$ and $\omega+n$ for finite nimbers $n$ as $\alpha'$ runs through the finites. This leaves $2\omega$ as the mex value.